# How to pass a string to a child view?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to pass the text in the textBox to the child view and create a scrollable Button there. As for the output status, we hope that 'a ~ c' are arranged vertically and that each is a button.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
  var textBox = ["a","b","c"]
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
        ForEach(0..<textBox.count) { number in
          ScrollText(text: self.textBox[number].lowercased())
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

struct ScrollText: View {
  @Binding  var text: String
  @State private var flag: Bool = false

  var body: some View {
    Button(action: {
      self.flag.toggle()
    }) {
      Text(text)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what is a problem with your code? try pass ref by using $  ScrollText(text: self.$textBox[number].lowercased())

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally clear what the problem is, or what you want, but I solved some compiler errors in your code, and it's showing three buttons as expected:

```swift
struct ContentView : View {
  var textBox = ["a","b","c"]
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false){
        ForEach(textBox, id: \.self) { letter in
          ScrollText(text: letter)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

struct ScrollText: View {
  var text: String
  @State private var flag: Bool = false

  var body: some View {
    Button(action: {
      self.flag.toggle()
    }, label: {
      Text(text)
    })
  }
}
```

Your question was how to pass a string, so you don't need `@Binding` for that. Just pass a string :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to keep `ScrollText` untouched the here is possible modifications in `ContentView` which uses it

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @State private var textBox = ["a","b","c"] // < make State, so modifiable
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
        ForEach(0..<textBox.count) { number in
          ScrollText(text: self.$textBox[number]) // < pass Binding as intended
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```